# EADDRINUSE Node.js MongoDB Callbacks issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, concurrency, callback, connection

The problem: (node.js application + mongodb Native driver)
I have a JSON file with more than 60000 Json Documents.the documents always a creation date and unique id called vid. and I need to insert in a MongoDB collection.
I need to insert the new vid  or update the ones already existing with another document more recent.

What I already did: 
https://github.com/TelmoIvo/PFC/blob/master/cfginit.js

What is happening: 
After inserting/updating like 500 times and getting 287 documents in collection I get this error:
AssertionError: null == { [MongoError: connect EADDRINUSE] name : 'MongoError', message: 'connect EADDRINUSE' } at the line assert.equal (null, err);

from what I read, it's saying I have the connection to DB already in use. but I close after I insert/update everytime.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't be calling `MongoClient.connect` every time. That's causing a ton of connections to open and close all the time which is overloading mongo. You should let the `MongoClient` manage the connection pool. Change it so that you store the db object from `MongoClient.connect` maybe in your init file add something like

```
//store this outside your init so its accessible to other functions
//this is what you will use to access the database
var db;

//add this to your init function
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, database){
    db = database;
}
```

Then in your functions to add and update use the `db` object you stored to update your collections and you won't need to keep opening connections. You can drop all the `MongoClient.connect` code and don't call `db.close()` since your connections are being shared to the object so let MongoClient manage them.